# app engine: development server time is off?

Tags: google-app-engine

Ok, I know I must be missing something, but my development server timestamp is off by 4 hours.  I am running Mac OS X Leopard Server.  The date command in a Terminal shows the correct time.  I am in Eastern Standard Time (GMT -5).  Is this a devserver setting?

Answer (score 2):

In production google app engine runs in UTC time, so the dev server modifies the timezone to also run in UTC time (although I've seen a case where that [doesn't work correctly](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/0fbb150ebcf674d2/8510797c5c5c1356)).

Are you in Eastern Standard Time (GMT-5) or Eastern Daylight Time (GMT-4)?

Comment: Good call on the correct time zone -- I am in EDT (GMT -4).  Is there a fix to get the devserver logs to display in the local timezone instead of UTC?

Comment: @Andrew: Not that I know of, although I haven't looked.